# Why are the "Enter name" output got skip over and when I type "close" in the output it keeps on looping

Tags: c

In the input below it keeps on looping when I type close in the output and after typing something in this part:

> Before proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End):

The "Enter name: " part got skip

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
      char name[200],gender[20],op,option, close;
      int visit_ID, phone_number,day,month,year,service_needed, change_service, needed_days;
      float service_fee,payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

      printf("\n\n*****Welcome to the Our Repair Centre*****");
      printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): ", close);
      scanf("%s", &close);

      FILE * fpointer;
      fpointer = fopen("visitdetails.txt","w");

      while(close != "close")
      {
          printf("\n\nEnter information:\n");
          printf("\nEnter name: ");
          scanf("%[^\n]s", name);
          printf("\n\nEnter your ID number(Number only): ", visit_ID);
          scanf("%d",&visit_ID);
          printf("\n\nEnter today date dd mm yy(use space) :");
          scanf("%d", &day);
          scanf("%d", &month);
          scanf("%d", &year);
          printf("\n\nEnter your gender(Male/Female): ", gender);
          scanf("%s",gender);
          printf("\n\nEnter your phone number: ",phone_number);
          scanf("%d",&phone_number);
          printf("\n\nDone registered\n\n");

          printf("*****Welcome to the Computer centre*****\n");
          printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
          printf("No |    Service Type                                    | Needed Days | Service Fee | \n");
          printf("                                                                      |Normal|Urgent|\n");
          printf("1. | Remove virus,Malware, or Spyware                   |      2      | 30RM | 50RM |\n");
          printf("2. | Troubleshot and fix computer running slow          |      2      | 40RM | 70RM |\n");
          printf("3. | Laptop Screen Replacement                          |      3      | 330RM| 430RM|\n");
          printf("4. | Laptop Keyboard Replacement                        |      2      | 160RM| 200RM|\n");
          printf("5. | Laptop Battery Replacement                         |      1      | 180RM| 210RM|\n");
          printf("6. | Operating System Format and Installation           |      2      | 50RM | 80RM |\n");
          printf("7. | Data Backup and Recovery                           |      2      | 100RM| 150RM|\n");
          printf("8. | Internet Connectivity issues                       |      1      | 50RM | 75RM |\n");

          printf("\nWhich service type do you need(1-8)? ", service_needed);
          scanf("%d",&service_needed);

          switch(service_needed)
          {
            case 1:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 30RM for Normal and 50RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
            scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            case 2:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 40RM for Normal and 70RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
            scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            case 3:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 330RM for Normal and 430RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
            scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            case 4:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 160RM for Normal and 200RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
            scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            case 5:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 180RM for Normal and 210RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
            scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            case 6:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 50RM for Normal and 80RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
            scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            case 7:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 100RM for Normal and 150RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
            scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            case 8:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 50RM for Normal and 75RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
            scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            default:
            printf("Invalid option");
          }
          printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): ", close);
          fprintf(fpointer, "Visit ID = %d", visit_ID);
          fprintf(fpointer, "\nCustomer name = %s", name);
          fprintf(fpointer, "\nLast visit date : %d/%d/%d",day,month,year);
          fprintf(fpointer,"\nLast Service type repaired: %d", service_needed);
          fscanf(fpointer,"%d",service_needed);
          fprintf(fpointer, "\nLast Service fee: %.2f",service_fee);
          fprintf(fpointer,"\nLast payment: %.2f",payment_made);
          fclose(fpointer);
      }
}
```

Comment: Use `strcmp` instead of `close != "close"`.

Comment: `close` is a single character. You need an array

Comment: Note that `scanf("%[^\n]s", name);` is neither one thing nor the other. The two string input formats are `%s` and `%[...]`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I've tried strcmp however it still gives me an error char close[100] = "close", off[100];                                                                             while((strcmp(close)==0)&&(strcmp(off)==0))

Comment: @KOKOAPU `strcmp()` needs to have two arguments. The string pointed to by the first argument is compared to the string pointed to by the second argument.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio        I've tried typing the output in this                                                             "printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): ", close);" And when I tried to type other than close, it is still proceeding to run.
      scanf("%s", &close);

      if(strcmp(close, "close"));
      {

Comment: @KOKOAPU You need to place `printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): "); scanf("%s", &close);` a second time at the end of the loop in order to input a string to the array `close` another time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several issues:

#### 1.

`close` is a single `char`. In order to use `scanf("%s", &close);` close needs to be at least an array of 2 characters for storing the newline. For storing a character only, use `%c` instead. If you want to at least store the word `"close"` in it, you need an array of 6 `char`.

#### 2.

`scanf("%s", &close);` leaves the newline made by the press to  in `stdin`.

This newline is catched by `scanf("%[^\n]s", name);`.

Use `"%*c"` after every conversion specifer for all format strings in your code like:    `scanf("%s %*c", &close);` to discard the newline.

#### 3.

Note, that `%[`is separate from `%s`. Omit the `s` at the end of the format string.

Also add a white space before the `%[` conversion specifier to catch leading white space.

Like: `scanf(" %[^\n]", name);`.

#### 4.

`while(close != "close)"` is incorrect to be used for comparing strings. Use  `while(strcmp(close, "close"))` instead. Also I think `if` would be more appropriate here: `if (strcmp(close, "close"))`

#### 5.

The `while` loop has no `break;` statement to get out of it. It will continue infinitely.

#### 6.

`fclose(fpointer);` is placed inside of the `while` loop. If you want to iterate the `while` loop´s body, you need to place it out of it.

#### 7.

`printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): ", close);` - `, close` is full redundant here. Omit it.

#### 8.

You should check whether the opening of the stream to `visitdetails.txt` was successful by checking the returned pointer of `fopen()` for a null pointer:

```
if (!(filePointer = fopen("visitdetails.txt", "w")))
{
    fputs("Error occurred at opening file!\n", stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: char name[200],gender[20],op,option, close[100];
      int visit_ID, phone_number,day,month,year,service_needed, change_service, needed_days;
      float service_fee,payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

      printf("\n\n*****Welcome to the Our Repair Centre*****");
      printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): ", close);
      scanf("%s", &close;

      FILE * fpointer;
      fpointer = fopen("visitdetails.txt","w");

      if(strcmp(close, "close"));

Comment: @KOKOAPU After `if(strcmp(close, "close"))` no `;`

Comment: I'm sorry I just started programming. I need to loop over and over again to get the customer detail and store it in file. However, can you explain  if(strcmp(close, "close")) how did it loop

Comment: @KOKOAPU Then you need to use `while(strcmp(close, "close"))`. But do you really want to repeat all inputs? How do you break out of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

As @Roberts told here that `YOUR CODE HAS SEVERAL ISSUES`. I wanna tell you that if you are going to launch this program at your repair center, you'll surely lose your customer. Your code is so much overwhelming, that it needs `AVENGER LEVEL` improvement. And I want to mention that please improve your UI, user-interaction with this program is worse. Although, I fixed your code at a tiny level, please check it out.
Please tell me that what you want to achieve throught this code, so that I can help you.

> Do you want to store every visitor's information who visited your repair center on a text file?
>   and What after a user inputs the service fee?

Please edit your question and tell us, what's your goal?

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // Added this header to use exit() function.
#include <string.h> // Added this header to use string related functions.

int main(void)
{
      char name[200], gender[20], op, option, close [6];//modified close to close[6];
      int visit_ID, phone_number, day, month, year, service_needed, change_service, needed_days;
      float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

      printf("\n\n*****Welcome to the Our Repair Center*****");
      printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): ");
      gets(close);

      FILE * fpointer;
      if((fpointer = fopen("visitdetails.txt", "w")) == NULL) // Checking for any error while opening the file in write mode.
      {
          perror("Write");
          exit(1);
      }

      while (strcmp(close, "close"))
      {
          printf("\n\nEnter information:\n");
          printf("\nEnter name: ");
          gets(name); //scanf("%[^\n]s", name);
          printf("\n\nEnter your ID number(Number only): ");
          scanf("%d", &visit_ID);
          printf("\n\nEnter today date dd mm yy(use space) :");
          scanf("%d %d %d", &day, &month, &year);
          fflush(stdin);
          printf("\n\nEnter your gender(Male/Female): ");
          gets(gender); //scanf("%s",gender);
          printf("\n\nEnter your phone number: ");
          scanf("%d", &phone_number);
          printf("\n\nDone registered\n\n");


          printf("*****Welcome to the Computer center*****\n");
          printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
          printf("No |    Service Type                                    | Needed Days | Service Fee | \n");
          printf("                                                                      |Normal|Urgent|\n");
          printf("1. | Remove virus,Malware, or Spyware                   |      2      | 30RM | 50RM |\n");
          printf("2. | Troubleshot and fix computer running slow          |      2      | 40RM | 70RM |\n");
          printf("3. | Laptop Screen Replacement                          |      3      | 330RM| 430RM|\n");
          printf("4. | Laptop Keyboard Replacement                        |      2      | 160RM| 200RM|\n");
          printf("5. | Laptop Battery Replacement                         |      1      | 180RM| 210RM|\n");
          printf("6. | Operating System Format and Installation           |      2      | 50RM | 80RM |\n");
          printf("7. | Data Backup and Recovery                           |      2      | 100RM| 150RM|\n");
          printf("8. | Internet Connectivity issues                       |      1      | 50RM | 75RM |\n");

          printf("\nWhich service type do you need(1-8)? ");
          scanf("%d", &service_needed);

          switch(service_needed)
          {
            case 1:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 30RM for Normal and 50RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
                scanf("%f", &service_fee);
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 40RM for Normal and 70RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
                scanf("%f", &service_fee);
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 330RM for Normal and 430RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
                scanf("%f", &service_fee);
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 160RM for Normal and 200RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
                scanf("%f", &service_fee);
                break;

            case 5:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 180RM for Normal and 210RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
                scanf("%f",&service_fee);
                break;

            case 6:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 50RM for Normal and 80RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
            scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            case 7:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 100RM for Normal and 150RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
            scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            case 8:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 50RM for Normal and 75RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
            scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            default:
            printf("Invalid option");
          }
          fflush(stdin);
          system("cls");
          printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): ", close);
          gets(close);
          fprintf(fpointer, "Visit ID = %d", visit_ID);
          fprintf(fpointer, "\nCustomer name = %s", name);
          fprintf(fpointer, "\nLast visit date : %d/%d/%d",day,month,year);
          fprintf(fpointer,"\nLast Service type repaired: %d", service_needed);
          fscanf(fpointer,"%d",service_needed);
          fprintf(fpointer, "\nLast Service fee: %.2f",service_fee);
          fprintf(fpointer,"\nLast payment: %.2f",payment_made);
          fclose(fpointer);
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes, indeed I need to store every customer that came in the store

Comment: after storing every customer, I need to search for visit detail based on the customer name @Lucas

Comment: Execute my code and tell me Is the output matches desired output? Was it you expected from your code?

Comment: @KOKOAPU Do you want to search the details using a text editor like ```notepad``` or you want to search it using another C program?

Comment: Actually I didn't post every code just partial because the comments are limited. I want to search it with C program

Comment: I'm focusing on the looping of the customer that's why I just post some of it

Comment: Change ```if (strcmp(close, "close"))``` to ```while (strcmp(close, "close"))``` for looping. @KOKOAPU

Comment: I've tried however it skips the "printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): "); at the end of the loop directly to "Enter name:" which made me unable to stop the looping @Lucas

Comment: Oh ! Ok, then my suggestion is to work more on user interaction of your program. You probably want to clear your console screen after a customer enters his/her details, so please use a function like ```system("cls")``` on windows or ```system("clear")``` on linux. Here **system()** function call and execute system commands.

Comment: @KOKOAPU just add ```fflush(stdin)``` before the ```printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): ", close);``` line and after this line add ```gets(close)``` at the end of the loop.

Comment: sorry wrong comment, what I mean is, Do you mean like this  default:
        printf("Invalid option");

      }
      system("cls");

Comment: btw can you explain more detail of fflush(stdin) can't seem to understand the use of it

Comment: I've tried this but it still didn't work and it still skips the Before Proceeding line at the end of the loop fflush(stdin) before the printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): ", close); line and after this line add gets(close) at the end of the loop.@LUCAS

Comment: Its used to flush or clear any unwritten data in stream's buffer. [fflush](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-file-handling/fflush-function-c/)

I'm executing this program in CodeBlocks IDE and its working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Btw the code didn't work in my place when i do it like this or is it wrong code                                                                                            system("clear");
      fflush(stdin);
      printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): ", close);
      gets(close); @Lucas

Comment: Can you show me any error u r getting or any warning? What's your IDE ?

Comment: It didn't have any error however loads of warning. One of them is :
data argument not used by format string [-Wformat-extra-args]
printf("\n\nBefore proceeding to our service, you need to fill in your details first as our record(type close to End): ", close); And I use Atom to code @Lucas

Comment: I just used codeblocks as well and I guess it's the same. Still skips the "before proceeding" line

Comment: Check the code section of this answer and again run it. @KOKOAPU